# Spool file larger than 4GB in sqlplus

Tags: linux, unix, sqlplus

I am selecting billions of queries from oracle database. Running sqlplus on RHEL 5. I am doing following:

```
>spool on
>set heading off
>set trimsp on pages 0
```

1) Problem is that spool file is becoming larger than 4GB and it doesn't write selected rows in this file after that.
How can i achieve that? (i found that resultant file should be larger approx. 9GB)

2) Also i don't want the result queries to be displayed on console. They should go directly in the spool file. (as it decreases the speed of this operation)

Comment: multiple queries with differing where clauses, output to appropriately named separate files? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Im not sure but according to this [source](https://community.oracle.com/message/801020#801020) there seems to be a limit on the size of spool file. Usually file system used also places limits on the size of the file. So this has something to do with file size limit perhaps.

2) For this you can add `SET ECHO OFF` which displays any output from coming onto the console